# Android Vertical screen percent divide

Tags: android

i write this xml file:

Up code work very fine, but i want this `android:src="@drawable/down"` image fit 80% of vertical screen,How can i do this?

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
         />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/downImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:src="@drawable/down" />
    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why have you taken multiple LinearLayouts for a single ImageView only?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly and you want to have two images one under another and the second should take 80% of the screen then this is solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
     />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/downImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:src="@drawable/down" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This answer is, in my opinion, the shortest and best solution. Forget nesting Layouts or something like that.